# Do Truffle methods automatically raise time-out exceptions?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, exceptions

Do the Solidity library functions automatically raise exceptions if a **time-out** error occurs? For example, what happens if the **sendCoin()** method call in this Truffle doc page times out (never completes)?:

http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts

If so, where can I read up on best practices for structuring your exception/error handling code to handle time-outs and on what the suggested recovery measures are to take for this specific type of error?

Answer (score 1):

> Do the Solidity library functions automatically raise exceptions if a
>   time-out error occurs?

While Truffle embarks a compiler, it is not truffle that executes the solidity smart-contracts compiled code directly. This is the role of the EVM. As EVM is not asynchronous as per nature of the network, it seems impossible to have what we could call a `timeout`.

> what happens if the sendCoin() method call in this Truffle doc page
>   times out (never completes)?

Your question might be more relevant then about handling the connexion through JavaScript, and in our case using truffle suite libraries.

[Truffle artifactor documentation](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-artifactor) and [truffle-contract documentation](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract) indicates using `promised functions` for most of the interactions with the network. You can use `then` and `catch` to handle your request.

**[it seems that the tools implements some kind of timeout](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/blob/d38c273fb1079cec73769a9999e82062728847a4/contract.js#L166), so yes.** After 240 seconds, the request `promise` would be `rejected` and would trigger the associated `catch` method.

If it weren't so, i guess some promises could get stuck forever and the next instructions of your JS process would never be executed.

Below an simple snippet to handle a request with `truffle-contract` library :

```
const myEthAddress = '0x0...A';
const myContractAddress = '0x0...F';
const myContractABI = require('myContractABI.json');
myContractABI.setProvider(myWeb3Instance.currentProvider);

myContract.at(myContractAddress).then( instance => {
            return instance.mySolidityMethod(arg1, arg2, { from: myEthAddress, gas : "1200000" });  
        }).then( res => {
            //  success of transaction
            console.log(res);
            return true;

        }).catch( e => {
            // transaction failure, error or timeout
            console.log(err); 
            return false;
        });
    }
```

For now, `truffle-contract` doesn't implement any flag that could be used to split behaviour between timeout and specific transaction failure response which is probably not considered as critical as Ethereum as a network is supposed to be resilient.

It only returns a string for which you could try to build a match in order to split the process depending on timeout or not if you believe it is worth it.

You'll find the current string on the [truffle-contract repo](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/blob/d38c273fb1079cec73769a9999e82062728847a4/contract.js#L193).

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea if the timeout value is settable by the smart contract developer?  For example, make it 30 seconds instead of 240?

Comment: the smart-contract developper has nothing to do with it, it'd be your JavaScript developper who should make modifications. (S)he'd have to fork it's own version of truffle-contract as the timeout value is hard-coded in the library

Comment: Excellent thanks.  At least I know where that time-out value is.